# Swift NSCoder Not Working For Double Variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nscoder

I'm restoring the state of my app and am storing a few variables using the NSCoder in Xcode 10.1. The NSCoder is fine at storing strings and other variable types, but won't allow me to store Doubles. I've tried numerous scenarios but it just doesn't seem to like Doubles!

If I convert the double into a string it will work. I've tried 'as? Double' and this still returns nil. Any ideas why I just can't use a Double?

```
override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    ...
    // Both don't work:
    coder.encode(myDoubleVariable, forKey: "Length")
    coder.encode(1.2345252, forKey: "Length")
}

override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    ... 
    // Both don't work:
    myDoubleVariable = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "Length") 
    myDoubleVariable = coder.decodeDouble(forKey: "Length") 
}
```

Comment: Define "don't work". And why not use `Codable` and avoid all of the Objective-C baggage of using `NSCoder`?

Comment: @rmaddy I can't use Codable in this scenario. The Double variable always returns nil on decodeRestorableState

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621461-encoderestorablestate

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621429-decoderestorablestate

Comment: They are both methods within UIViewController fro restoring state-related information for a view controller.

Comment: Have you verified they are actually being called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182965/discussion-between-dgee4-and-rmaddy).

Comment: Yeah definitely being called